# SSIS Script Task appears to run, but actually doesn't

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a script task  that *appears* as running fine, but no matter what I put inside nothing ever get executed.  I tried all sort of stuff: logging via the built in SSIS Logging mechanism, logging through additional variables and SQL Command task and I can never figure what's wrong.  I tried to put breakpoint and it won't break during debugging.

This is VS 2015 with SQL 2016.  This issue happens only when deployed on *one of the SQL Server*.  I previously has no issue at all at that server.  I deployed the same package on a different SQL box (same configuration) and it ran as expected.

EDIT: To better clarify the problem I started a new SSIS Package, it only 3 script tasks in it:

Test Task:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }
```

Once the Test Task is completed, it is linked to a "Success Task" if the test is successful, a "Fail Task" if it fails.

[image: simple test package]

On VS, the test task fail as expected and goes to the fail task.  However once deployed it stop working.

[image: Package Execution on VS]

[image: Package Execution on SQL]

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 things you can check:

**(1) The TargetServerVersion property**

Check that you are selecting the appropriate `TargetServerVersion` property

```
GoTo Project Properties >> Configuration Properties >> TargetServerVersion
```

[image]

**(2) ForceExecutionResult property Value**

Click on `Fail Task` and press <kbd>F4</kbd> to show the perperty Tab, check that `ForceExecutionResult` is set to `False`.

**(3) Run in 32-bit mode**

Try running the package in 32-bit mode:

```
GoTo Project properties >> Debugging >> Run64BitRuntime  = False
```

[image]